# Accepting an answer that doesn't exactly fit the question but provides a different solution

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked a question on Stackoverflow and I received one answer. The answer does not really answer my question, but does provide a possible solution, although it was the solution I was trying to avoid. Am I right to not accept the answer, or should I accept it just so my acceptance rate doesn't look poor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you said that was the solution you were hoping to avoid, you should certainly consider accepting it.  Even if you said you were hoping to avoid it, if the answer presents cogent reasons why it is the way to go, you should probably accept it.

You could decide to offer a bounty to see whether that attracts alternative solutions.